# how to fix gcc errors while installing mlpy using pip3

Tags: pip

I am trying to install mlpy using the below command:

pip3 install mlpy

and getting the below error messages:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/python-3.8.0/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7myxhgle/mlpy_b2919a30aa7e4592ab97d9f788fb9a11/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7myxhgle/mlpy_b2919a30aa7e4592ab97d9f788fb9a11/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-c9m7gaj0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/python-3.8.0/include/python3.8/mlpy Check the logs for full command output.
```

i am using tried to use the below gcc versions :

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.1.0

or
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

or

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 10.1.0

getting the same error messages , my OS is :

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)